# AWS Glue Scala String to Seq[Product]

Tags: scala, aws-glue

I have a scala glue job that takes the following for applymapping.

```
val applymapping1 = datasource0.applyMapping(mappings = Seq(("seqnum", "long", "seqnum", "long")), caseSensitive = false, transformationContext = "applymapping1")
```

However, I want to pass a variable in place "seqnum", "long", "seqnum", "long" and when I try I keep getting an error that says

```
Found String, Required Seq[Product].
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What do you pass to get that error?

Comment: I try to get it as a job parameter, like val mapping1 = args("MAPPING") and use it in applyMapping like applyMapping(mappings = Seq(mapping1), I get this error. error: type mismatch; found : String required: Product val applymapping1 = datasource0.applyMapping(mappings = Seq(mapping1), caseSensitive = false, transformationContext = "applymapping1")

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when you pass a string as `mapping` argument instead of `Seq`:

```
val applymapping1 = datasource0.applyMapping(
    mappings = "<string>", 
    caseSensitive = false, 
    transformationContext = "applymapping1"
)
```

However, in the code you provided it looks good and does work for me:

```
val applymapping1 = datasource0.applyMapping(
    mappings = Seq(("seqnum", "long", "seqnum", "long")), 
    caseSensitive = false, 
    transformationContext = "applymapping1"
)
```

Please make sure you run exactly this script.

**Update**

The same can be done by extracting mapping into a variable and then use it in `applyMapping`:

```
val mapping1 = ("seqnum", "long", "seqnum", "long")
val applymapping1 = datasource0.applyMapping(
    mappings = Seq(mapping1), 
    caseSensitive = false, 
    transformationContext = "applymapping1"
)
```

Comment: This one works for me too, but I would like to be able to pass a parameter in place of ("seqnum", "long", "seqnum", "long") that represents the same.            Eg. val finalmap1 : Product = args("MAPPING").asInstanceOf[Product4[String,String,String,String]]                  val applymapping1 = datasource0.applyMapping(mappings = Seq((finalmap1)), caseSensitive = false, transformationContext = "applymapping1")

Comment: Answer updated with using a variable instead of inline mapping

Comment: This one works fine. Thanks. However, when I try to get it as a job parameter, like val mapping1 = args("MAPPING") and use it in applyMapping like applyMapping(mappings = Seq(mapping1), I get this error. error: type mismatch; found : String required: Product val applymapping1 = datasource0.applyMapping(mappings = Seq(mapping1), caseSensitive = false, transformationContext = "applymapping1")